# Use a .dll-library in React Native

Tags: react-native, dllimport

We plan to rewrite a app, which was developed with Xamarin previously with React Native. The Xamarin-app used a dll-library to connect and communicate with a hardware device through bluetooth.

Is it possible to use this .dll-library in the new React Native app? Can we wrap this .dll-library with a Native Module to use it in RN?

The app will be developed for iOS and Android – So, we have to wrap the dll for each operating system?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: you possibly need to search about jni/ndk and wrap your dll with an interface. also take a look and search if your dll is managed or unmanaged for the right approche